# Why does my code not return anything?

Tags: c, file-io

It is suppose that to an entry such as:

```
1 1 524 5 true -1
```

where the first parameter is the `idOrder`, the second parameter is the number of products in `idOrder`, the third parameter is a code, the fourth parameter is the amount of products, the fifth parameter is a boolean to distinguish the product and the sixth parameter is the final mark.

It should return an output such as:

```
524 -1 5
```

where the first parameter is the code of the product, the second parameter is the final mark and the third parameter is the amount of products.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef enum {false, true} bool;

int main()
{
    const int END = -1;

    int idOrder, numProducts, idCodeProduct, amount, total, temp;
    bool generic, endSeq;

    scanf("%d", temp);
    /*printf("%d ", temp);*/
    idOrder = temp;
    endSeq = temp == END;

    if (endSeq != true) {
        total = 0;
        scanf("%d", &temp);
        numProducts = temp;
        scanf("%d", &temp);
        idCodeProduct = temp;
        scanf("%d", &temp);
        amount = temp;
        scanf("%d", &temp);
        generic = temp;

        if (generic == true) {
            total = total + amount;
            printf("%d", idCodeProduct);
        }
    }
    printf("%d ", END);
    printf("%d ", total);
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this code, it doesn't return anything at all and I don't know why.

Comment: Do you try to `scanf` the boolean *string* as a number? That won't work very well.

Comment: Are you sure about `scanf("%d", temp);
` line that this is not written as `scanf("%d", &temp);
`?

Comment: fixed! I made a mistake

Comment: Also note that there is no need for the `temp` variable, you can scan directly into the final variables.

Comment: you are trying to load as numbers `true`,?

Comment: 1) `scanf("%d", temp);` -->` scanf("%d", &temp); Anonymous 2) "it doesn't return anything" is confusing.  `main()` returns `0`, what did you want it to return?  3) **Append** edits like "Changed `scanf("%d ", &temp);` to `scanf("%d", &temp);` Ref @Joachim Pileborg but still having _detailed_problem_report_."  By changing the code, it makes answers look non-applicable to the present post and invites closure.  4) "true" is text and not a numeric value that `scanf()` will convert.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have a trailing whitespace in the format codes to `scanf`. While this causes `scanf` to read and discard whitespace, it also causes `scanf` to *read until it finds a non-whitespace*. If there's nothing more to read, then `scanf` will wait indefinitely for more input.

Drop the trailing space in the format and it should work better. As long as you are scanning for normal strings or numbers you have to remember that `scanf` actually skips leading whitespace automatically.

I recommend you read e.g. [this `scanf` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf).

Comment: I removed the whitespaces from scanf and my code is still not working.

Comment: @david_doji Step through the code in a debugger, line by line, to see where it stops.

Answer (score 1):

1) Remove trailing space in formats as suggested by @Joachim Pileborg.

2) Change `temp` to `&temp` as suggested by @Anonymous

3) Do not try to read "true" as an `int` as comment ed by @BLUEPIXY.  Read as string and convert.

4) No need for `temp` @Joachim Pileborg

5) Always check `scanf()` results.

6) Initialize total

7) Avoid your own `typedef enum {false, true} bool;`, use `stdbool.h`

8) Simplify

```
int main() {

  const int END = -1;
  char tf[6];
  int idOrder, numProducts, idCodeProduct, amount;
  int total = 0;
  bool generic, endSeq;

  for (;;) {
    if (scanf("%d", &idOrder) != 1)
      Handle_BadInput();
    endSeq = idOrder == END;
    if (endSeq)
      break;
    if (scanf("%d%d%d%5s", &numProducts, &idCodeProduct, &amount, tf) != 4)
      Handle_BadInput();
    if (strcmp(tf, "true") == 0)
      generic = true;
    else if (strcmp(tf, "false") == 0)
      generic = false;
    else
      Handle_BadInput();
    if (generic) {
      total = total + amount;
      printf("%d ", idCodeProduct);  // add space
    }
  }
  printf("%d ", END);
  printf("%d ", total);
  return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`scanf` takes a pointer. `scanf("%d", &temp);`

Comment: I change it as you suggest and I get the same result!